# How to get the number of rows in a JTable that are not null?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

`getRowCount()` gets the number of rows that are set so i can't use it.

This is what I did and it doesn't work:

```
private String[][] getContentsFromTable(){
    int cols= jTable1.getColumnCount();
    int rows=jTable1.getRowCount();
    System.out.print(rows);
    String items[][]= new String[rows][cols];
    if(jTable1.getCellEditor()!=null)
        jTable1.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();        
    for(int i=0;i< jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<jTable1.getColumnCount();j++){
            //skip subtotal
            if(j!=3){
                if(jTable1.getValueAt(i,j)!=null){
                    String om=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();

                    if(om.trim().length()!=0){
                        items[i][j]=om;
                        //System.out.print(""+i+",j "+j+": "+items[i][j]);
                }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return items;

}
```

edit: the table is editable and i need to get all the data from rows so i have to go over it and identify the number of not null rows so i can use them in a loop and store the data in the database

Comment: What do you mean "the number of rows that are set"?  JTable's getRowCount() will return the number of rows in the view.  This may or may not correspond to the number of rows in the underlying TableModel, which also exposes a getRowCount() method.  You should not have to concern yourself with "null" rows; that suggests something strange with your design.

Comment: the table is editable and has to be populated. i need to get all the data from rows so i have to go over it and identify the number of not null rows so i can use them in a loop and store the data in the database

Answer (score 0):

Kind of too late but for anyone who is having problems with NULL rows, .getValueAt is throwing a null exception so do not try to use it for checking null rows.